# How can I access the request parameters in the onResponse and the onFailure callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a Retrofit call where I want to handle HTTP and Retrofit errors when calling an API.

So when a failure happens, I need to cache the request into a RoomDB/SQLite for when the API comes back online, or connection improves there is a routine that sends all those requests to the API.

```
x.enqueue(object : Callback<PayloadResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<PayloadResponse>,
                response: Response<PayloadResponse>
            ) {

                ...
                val errorMessage = when {
                    response.code() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK -> {

                    // Need the original Payload here so I can insert that data into RoomDB/SQLite 

                    "An error occured duing API Call (NOT OK) &{response.code()}"

                    }
                    ...
```

Same situation I need for the onFailure() callback.

Can I access the original request in these contexts? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Once I have encountered the same problem. My approach was debugging first parameter of retrofit callback's onResponse and onFailure.

```
call: Call<PayloadResponse>

call.request()
```

It contains all kind of information about your call / request e.g url, parameters, method. However, retrieving request data is not straightforward, consistent, and prone to bugs.

Then, I started using Kotlin coroutine which gives async process with sync nature of coding.

```
interface RetrofitApi{

    @GET("your-route")
    suspend fun sampleApiMethod(request:SampleRequest):Response<SampleCustomObject>
}
```

Your retrofit api methods may look like above.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val request = SampleRequest()
        val deferred = async { apiService.sampleApiMethod(request) }
        val result = deferred.await()
        if(result.code() == 200){
            // Do something
        }else{
            // Cache SampleRequest()
        }
    }
```

You can modify as much as to make it look better and utilize optimized light weight threads. It is one of the ways for me to handle such situations. It's just a hint, you may modify to have structurally and architecturally correct design in your project.